# An error with sudo command

Tags: sudo, laravel

I used 'chmod -7 RRR'(without quotes) from one of my project directories without any options(eg. folder name - I usually use 'chmod -R 777 storage/logs' - for getting logs written into the logs file inside lumen/laravel project).

Now whenever I use sudo command I get the result:
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Can someone help me in this regard?

Comment: `chmod -7 RRR` would have removed all permission for `others` from a directory named `RRR` (if it existed). Are you sure that's what you typed?

Comment: I suspect you actually ran `chmod -R 777` and that you ran the command as root and in either the `/` or the `/etc` directory. Is that what you did?

Comment: Hmm... doesn't chmod require at least one file operand anyhow?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R` is an obsolete and dangerous method of controlling access. Stop using it now. This isn't DOS. Learn about Linux users, groups, and permissions. You seem to have broken your system by applying your old method  to system directories (maybe just `/etc`, but possibly `/`). The last time I checked, the `/` directory contained thousands of files and directories with over a dozen different permission bit values. You have set them all to `777 rwxrwxrwx`, clearing any SETUID/SETGID permission bits. Reinstall.